# Calculate $\lim _{x\to 0+}\left(\frac{e^x+3x-1}{x}\right)$

Tags: limits

I need help with finding a limit without using L'Hopital's rule.
$\lim _{x\to 0+}\left(\frac{e^x+3x-1}{x}\right)$

The answer is 4.

any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: use fact that lim_0 (e^x-1)/x=1

Answer (score 4):

One may recall that, for any differentiable function in the neighborhood of $a$, one has
$$
\lim _{x\to a}\left(\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\right)=f'(a)
$$ then applying it with $f(x)=e^x+3x$ and $a=0$ gives the answer $f'(0)=e^0+3=4$.

Comment: Congratulations for the $99,999$ rep !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you! This was planified :)

Answer (score 2):

If you can use that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$ (if not - try to prove it), thus
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{e^x +3x - 1}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{e^x-1}{x} +\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{3x}{x} = 1 + 3=4.
$$

Comment: The latter limit corresponds to the definition of the derivative at $x=0$. Needless to use substitution.